# Meteor: Building a custom form and need help redirecting after submission

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

EDIT: I did add `action="/results"` to the form element but it does not do anything. I also set the page `/results` on my routes.

New to Meteor and I'm working on a app that collect form entries for multiple categories. Form is custom built:

```
/*------------------- Template.html ----------------------------*/
<form class="word_of_day">
    <div class="page 1 view">
       <h1>Word of the day</h1>
       <p>Enter the word and fill out the fields as you go.</p>
       <input type="text" name="word" placeholder="Word of the day" />
    </div>
    <div class="page 2">
        {{> day_two}}
    </div>
    <div class="page 3">
        {{> day_three}}
    </div>
    <div class="page 4">
        {{> day_four}}
    </div>
    <div class="page 5">
        {{> day_five}}
        <div class="error"></div>
        <div class="pull-down">
           <span>Would you like to send this to yourself? (not required)</span>
           <input type="text" name="user_email" placeholder="Your Email" />
        </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>                  
</form>


/*---------------------- app.js ---------------------------------------*/
Template.form.events({
"submit .word_of_day":function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Currently I have the form pushing the data into the Collections I have created but I can't figure out how to redirect the form after submission. I have flow-router set up on the app, not sure if that helps. I appreciate any help and guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your events

```
"submit .word_of_day":function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  Meteor.call('updateYourData', $(event.target).serializeArray(), function(err, res){
      if (!err) {
          FlowRouter.go('path/to/some-where');
      }

  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I have Meteor.call() method being used for emailing the results so I just plugged in the `function(err, data){ if(!err){FlowRouter.go('path/to/some-where');}`

Comment: Glad that i could help